# c++ inheritance pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers

it's pretty diffecult for me to describe my problem. 
I have two classes, I would say `Base_A` and `Derived_A`. You can see from the names, the class `Derived_A` is derived from `Base_A`. Also in my program I have other two classes `Base_B` and `Derived_B` (also with inheritance). The class `Base_A` contains the object of `Base_B`, and the class `Derived_A` contains the object of `Derived_B`.

```
class Base_A {
public:
    Base_A() {}
    virtual ~Base_A() {}

    Base_B b_;
    Base_B* pointer_;

    void init() {
        b_ = Base_B();
        pointer_ = &b_;
        pointer_->setValue(1);
    }

    void print() {
        pointer_->getValue();

    }
};

class Derived_A: public Base_A {
public:
    Derived_A() {}
    virtual ~Derived_A() {}

    Derived_B b_;
    Derived_B* pointer_;

    void init() {
        b_ = Derived_B();
        pointer_ = &b_;
        pointer_->setValue(2);
        pointer_->increaseValue();
    }
};

class Base_B {
public:
    Base_B() {}
    virtual ~Base_B() {}

    int value_;

    void setValue(int value) {
        value_ = value;
    }

    void getValue() {
        cout << "Base_B: " << value_ << endl;
    }
};

class Derived_B: public Base_B {
public:
    Derived_B() {}
    virtual ~Derived_B() {}

    void increaseValue() {
        value_++;
    }
};

int main() {  
    Derived_A derived_A = Derived_A();
    derived_A.init();
    derived_A.print();

    return 0;
}
```

How you can see every class of A has one object of class B and pointer to this object. My problem is, when I call the function `print()`, it does not take `Derived_B* pointer_`, but try to access `Base_B* pointer_`, which is not exist. How I can say in my program, that it should take the pointer according to the class? Or do I need to declarate the `Base_B* pointer_` inside the `Derived_A` class like:

```
Base::pointer_ = pointer_;
```

Maybe is there other method or algorithm for my problem?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: you could create a virtual function that returns the appropriate pointer. Are you aware that Derived_A has two `pointer_`s ?

Comment: yes, I know that Derived_A has two pointers. It was just an example. In the real program, this pointers have different names. And about your idea. Do you mean, that I need the function that return me a pointer of class B and than give this pointer to function print()?

Comment: Either that or directly put that method call in print(). You could also make print virtual and override it in the derived class. I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: As a further remark, I also doubt whether BaseA should contain a BaseB. This means that DerivedA contains TWO BaseB's, one the base class and one in the DerivedB member. I'd look at creating an abstract base class; Cf. Meyer's recommendation on "make non-leaf classes abstract".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"but try to access `Base_B*` pointer_, which is not exist"

If `DerivedA` does not properly initialise `BaseA`, then `DerivedA` does not meet the "isA" rule for inheritance and the design needs changed. On the face of things:

1. Don't re-use names in the derived class such as `b_`, `pointer_`.
   Its just confusing and you gain no value.
2. Make init() virtual.
3. Have DerivedA::init() call BaseA::init() explicitly.
4. Make pointer_  a virtual method.

Note the use of "covariant return types" for the virtual methods.

```
class BaseA
    {
    public:
       virtual BaseB* pointer() { return &b_; }
       // etc.
    };

class DerivedA : public BaseA
    {
    public:
       virtual DerivedB* pointer() { return &b_; }
       // etc.
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't Base_A have a pointer to Base_B if Base_A::init() was ever called?
why wouldn't you init the base class?

Comment: I thought more about to override the value Base_B* pointer_, when I init() the class Derived_A. The same like I can override the virtual function in inheritance. Or maybe use Templates that the pointer_, can have different types. But I don't know how exactly.